# how to read dynamic checkboxes without using id attribute of checkbox control in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have a web application in which I am dynamically generating and displaying checkboxes at runtime. Each checkbox corresponds to an item. I need to find which items are selected. However I cannot set the id of the item in the ID attribute of Checkbox control while generating the control as the same item can appear multiple times on the web page.The ID attribute enables me to use the Page.Form() method but now I cannot use. Please suggest an alternate method to find which checkboxes are checked.

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamically generating"? Are you creating a list of CheckBoxes in server-side code, or is the CheckBox being created by an event? Either way, your server-side code should enable you to set the `ID` property of your CheckBox, so I would set it to something like `checkboxN` where N is a positive integer that grows with each new ID. That way you can retrieve a particular check box without having to know its value.

Comment: How are these dynamically generated .. in short code plz

Answer (score 1):

If you use [JQUERY](http://jquery.com) you can assign a common class to each checkbox and then use a "class selector" to get an array of items on a page that all have the same class. With that you may iterate through the array and identify which items have been checked.
The relevant code will look something like:

```
<head>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function findCheckedBoxes() {
            var AllBoxes = $(".productCheckBox");
            for(i=0;i<AllBoxes.length; i++)
            {
                if(AllBoxes[i].checked)
                {
                    //do something with it...
                    alert(AllBoxes[i].value);
                }
                }
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server" onsubmit="return validatefields();">
    <input id="Checkbox1" type="checkbox" class="productCheckBox" value="one" />One<br />
    <input id="Checkbox2" type="checkbox" class="productCheckBox" value="two" />Two<br />
    <input id="Checkbox3" type="checkbox" class="productCheckBox" value="three" />Three<br />
    <input id="Checkbox4" type="checkbox" class="productCheckBox" value="four" />Four<br />
    <input id="Button2" type="button" value="button" onclick="findCheckedBoxes()" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: +1 for your website... best entertainment I've had in ages ;-)

Comment: I am Sorry I don't have any knowledge of Jquery. I was looking for an ASP.net solution. Thanks anyways!

Comment: @vjain27, you really need to add jquery to your toolbox. It works on the client, where ASP.NET is principally a server side technology.

Comment: @vjain27 wondering how you would achieve your asp.net solution without an **id**

Comment: @Cos Callis - But with jquery how would I be able to read the checkboxes at the server side ?

Comment: @vjain27, there are a number of ways to approach that question. Inside the findCheckedBoxes function you can set value(s) that will get passed back (in hidden inputs for instance) to the server. Another option would be to pass back discrete check/uncheck events to page methods using ajax. If you are dynamically creating these on the server-side then after page_load they should be available like any other control... The answer is "how do you want to read them"?